# Change button foreground color on button click

Tags: c#, uwp

In windows phone 8, I was using this

```
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyButton.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((System.Windows.Media.Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneForegroundColor"]);
}
```

to change button button foreground color to phone accent color.

But what should I use for UWP?

Comment: I haven't voted down your question, however it clearly (as for me) lacks research/effort shown. Take a look [at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources). Also you may use designer/Blend and get your aswer quite easy. By the way - I would do this by VisualStates rather than changes in the code.

Comment: I don't know about your project, I just pointed other option, I really don't care if you use it or not.  What kind of moderation power I use unfairly?

Comment: Of course I don't know your project, and if you read my comment carefully you will notice that I've written that your **question** lacks research/effort. Your project has nothing to do with this. I also pointed that Blend/designer could have give you an answer about specific resources, even without using it inside your project. You are still talking about this unfairly applied power - can you enlighten me about that? I would like to know what powers I have used, because as far as I know I haven't done nothing extraordinary, also many other normal users could have done the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush` directly.

```
MyButton.Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush"];
```

You can replace "PhoneForegroundColor" with "SystemAccentColor" too.

Answer (score 1):

```
 MyButton.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0)); //OpacRed
```